# Perl Error: Can' t call method 'Mangle' on an undefined value

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute a perl script in that we have statement like this-

```
# Calculate password using PwdMangler
$PwdMangler = Win32::OLE->new('PWDMangler.Mangler');
unless($password = $PwdMangler->Mangle($user , $password_plain))
{
  print $log_file "Error occured in PwdMangler\n";
  exit (1);
} # End Unless
```

but this perl is giving an error like this-

Can't call method 'Mangle' on an undefined value.

So, i tried to print $user and $password_plain values and i am able to capture these values.

Any suggestion for this error.

Comment: It's `$PwdMangler` that's undefined. There's probably an issue with the OLE thing.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix that?

Comment: `Win32::OLE->LastError()` might specify why `Win32::OLE->new('PWDMangler.Mangler')` is failing.

Comment: Please try to add the following code to your program. It will show the list of available programs for OLE.

    `$Count = Win32::OLE->EnumAllObjects(sub {
            my $Object = shift;
            my $Class = Win32::OLE->QueryObjectType($Object);
            printf "# Object=%s Class=%s\n", $Object, $Class;
        });`

Comment: Code looks bad in comments and I'm not sure how to deal with it...

Comment: i tried win32::ole_>lasterror() and got this- the error is Win32::OLE
0.1709) error 0x80040154: "Class not registered"

Comment: i tried this too- my $Count = Win32::OLE->EnumAllObjects(sub { my $Object = shift; my $Class = Win32::OLE->QueryObjectType($Object); printf "# Object=%s Class=%s\n", $Object, $Class; });
print "the count is: $Count"; and i am getting " the count is 0"

Comment: is there any issue with OLE.PM file?

Answer (score 0):

From CPAN: The `new()` class method starts a new instance of an OLE Automation object. It returns a reference to this object or `undef` if the creation failed.

You should check if the `PWDMangler.Mangler` is a proper program id.

P.S.: Don't want to look dumb, but are you sure that `PWDMangler` should not be `PWDManager`?